# Return non Class type from Collectors.partitioningBy

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

In this example

```
Stream<MyClass>stream = Stream.of(new MyClass(5),new MyClass(15),new MyClass(8),new MyClass(12));

Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map =
        stream.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(a->a.getNum()<10));
```

the `stream.collect` retrieves a map of Boolean and `List<MyClass>` so it doesn't work. What should I do to return a map of `Boolean` and `List<Integer>` instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, when you want a different aggregation in a `groupingBy` or `partitioningBy` operation, you’d do it by specifying another `Collector` like in:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map
    = stream.collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(a -> a.getNum()<10,
        Collectors.mapping(MyClass::getNum, Collectors.toList())));
```

however, when both, the partitioning function and the aggregation function, work on the same property, it’s much easier to `map` the elements to that property value upfront:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map2
    = stream.map(MyClass::getNum).collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(num -> num<10));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the two argument version of [`partitioningBy(predicate, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-), which accepts a downstream collector:

```
Map<Boolean, List<Integer>> map = 
    stream.collect(partitioningBy(a->a.getNum() < 10, mapping(MyClass::getNum, toList())));
```

This downsteam collector maps each `Myclass` element of the Stream to their `num` and collects that into a `List`.

Static imports used:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.mapping;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.partitioningBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```